# What is meant by bionomics of a vector?

Tags: zoology, terminology, parasitology

What is supposed to fall under the title **Bionomics** (The study of an organism and its relation to its environment; ecology.)?

Suppose we are dealing with a vector, Anopheles sp. are the following going to be included in its bionomics:

1. Life cycle
2. Interaction with parasite (Plasmodium sp.)
3. Mode of transmission of parasite by this vector
4. Control
5. Diseases caused ?

Answer (score 3):

Bionomics is indeed the 'thorough' study of living organisms and their relationship with the environment/ niche they thrive in.

Aim of Bionomics is mainly to decipher the driving factors for an organism to prefer a given niche. Given this key goal, it is apparent that one needs to focus on all aspects of an organism's life cycle and community dynamics.

So the answer to your question would be: Yes, one will need to focus on all the five points pertaining to Anopheles sp. (the 5th point i.e diseases caused) will more be an information resulting out of the study of its interactions with other living/ non-living forms), than a specific focal point for Bionomics.

References:

[A good article on Bionomics](http://www.biotechnologyforums.com/thread-7738.html)

[An amazing and detailed report on Bionomics of Entomophagous Coleoptera](http://krishikosh.egranth.ac.in/handle/1/2033779)

Other references:

**The dominant Anopheles vectors of human malaria in Africa, Europe and the Middle East: occurrence data, distribution maps and bionomic précis. Sinka et al., 2010**

**Description and Bionomics of Anopheles (Cellia) ovengensis (Diptera: Culicidae), a New Malaria Vector Species of the Anopheles nili Group from South Cameroon. Awono-ambene et al., 2004**